# При добавлении в строку за последним символом символа '\0' программа выдаёт какой-то путь в конце строки. Вывод прилагается

Tags: c++, строки

При добавлении в строку за последним символом символа '\0' программа выдаёт какой-то путь в конце строки.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string S1, S2;
    getline(cin, S1);
    int i = 0, a = 0, space = 0;
    while (S1[i] == ' ' && S1[i] != '\0')//Ïðîïóñêàåì ïðîáåëû
    {
        i++;
    }
    cout << "i1: " << i << endl;
    S1.erase(a, i);//Óäàëÿåì ïðîáåëû èç ñòðîêè
    cout << "n: " << S1 << endl;
    i = 0;
    while (S1[i] != '\0')//Óäàëåíèå ïðîáåëëîâ ìåæäó ñëîâàìè
    {
        if (S1[i] == ' ' && space == 0)
        {
            space = 1;
            i++;
            S2 += ' ';
        }
        if (S1[i] == ' ' && space == 1)
        i++;
        if (S1[i] != ' ' && space == 1)
        {
            space = 0;
            S2 += S1[i];
            i++;
        }
        if (S1[i] != ' ' && space == 0)
        {
            S2 += S1[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    i = S2.size() - 1;
    while (S2[i] == ' ')
    {
        S2.erase(i);
        i--;
    }
    cout << "i2: " << i << endl;
    int r;
    while (S2[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (S2[i] != ' ')
            r = i;
            i++;
        }
    S2[r] = '\0';
    cout << "S2: " << S2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод прилагается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что вы вообще хотите от кода?

Comment: Вообще-то строка `string` не гарантирует наличие нулевого символа в ней.. Кстати, очень забавное условие - `while(S1[i] == ' ' && S1[i] != '\0')` - какой в нем смысл - если уж `S1[i]` пробел, то уж конечно он не ноль :) И еще - по правилам *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.* - где описание, например, желаемого поведения?

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, если мой код доставляет какие-то негативные эмоции. Он нужен для того, чтобы удалить пробелы между словами, в начале и конце строки.

Comment: @Harry, вроде нормальное условие - автор ищет первый непроблельный символ в строке

Comment: @Иван Соломенников, вы слишком усложнили свой код - СЛИШКОМ!!!, а выводит вам другую строку потому что вы вышли за пределы своей строки и залезли в другую область памяти и попали на вторую строку

Comment: Понимаю. Я только учусь. И понятное дело, что я не должен был писать сюда такой, возможно бессмысленный вопрос. Вы вправе поставить мне минус за мой вопрос, но всё же мне интересно, почему код выдаёт некий путь, после удаления пробелов?

Comment: А как не залазить в эту "другую" область памяти?

Comment: Например - непробельный символ.

Comment: @Zhihar Идем по строке. Если символ `S[i]` - пробел, то он **не может быть нулем**, и второе условие не нужно. Если это **не пробел** - все условие ложно - и зачем тогда вторая часть условия? Понятно теперь, о чем я?

Comment: @Harry, а да, ступил :)

Comment: Ничего. Спасибо за участие в обсуждении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы реализуете то, что называется `trim` - т.е. отрезаете от строки с обоих концов пробелы (ну и прочие пробельные символы, типа табуляции)

`find_first_not_of` - ищется первая позиция, не содержащая символы из списка
`find_last_not_of` - ищется последняя позиция в строке, не содержащая символы из списка

Поскольку вы пишите на C++ - используйте силу C++, ведь для работы со строкой есть уже нужные функции

```
std::string& ltrim(std::string& str, const std::string& chars = "\t\n\v\f\r ")
{
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(chars));
    return str;
}
 
std::string& rtrim(std::string& str, const std::string& chars = "\t\n\v\f\r ")
{
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(chars) + 1);
    return str;
}
 
std::string& trim(std::string& str, const std::string& chars = "\t\n\v\f\r ")
{
    return ltrim(rtrim(str, chars), chars);
}
```

и теперь можете вызывать

```
const std::string new_str = trim(old_str);
```

Comment: Хмм. Я не научился ещё использовать std:: но я понимаю, что без этого, видимо никак. спасибо вам большое. сейчас найду, как поставить вам плюс.

Comment: @Иван Соломенников, можно было бы и не использовать эти функции - а например пройтись по строке слева на права и найти место где кончается пробел и справа на лево и найти где кончается пробел - и вот у вас уже есть `pos_left` и `pos_right` и вам нужна будет строка между этими позициями, т.е. вариантов решения задачи много, но приведённый в ответе самый короткий,

Comment: Извините, можно спросить. А какие библиотеки необходимы для вашего метода.

Comment: @Иван Соломенников, `#include <string>`, которая по хорошему нужна и для просто использования `std::string`

Comment: @ИванСоломенников, если хотите научиться программировать, то конечно, ознакомьтесь с std::, а потом реализуйте оснвные идеи сами, на уровне манипуляции байтами